# Create a symbolic link depending on current network?

Tags: networking, windows-10, symbolic-link

I would like to create symbolic links that link to different folders depending on the network I'm currently connected to. Is that possible?

When I'm connected to my LAN, I want to work directly on the shared folder (symlink to \server\folder).
But when I'm on the move, I would like to work on the local copy of the folder (c:\localcopy\folder).

This would allow me to transparently open the correct folder.

I'm on Windows 10.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What will trigger the link creation? Will you restart whenever you change networks? If not, how do you register a network change?

Comment: This cannot be done with symbolic links.

Comment: I was thinking there could be a way of creating "conditional" links that could check the current network connection. But apparently, that's not possible. Do you know of any other way of doing that?